# IronPython gzip

Tags: ironpython, gzip

Is there a direct equivalent of gzip for IronPython?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IronPython - How do I import Gzip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734593/ironpython-how-do-i-import-gzip)

Answer (score 0):

Yup. After half a second's Googling:

http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2006-September/003608.html

Comment: Sorry - I dont know why I didn't see it. I get the following error:    Could not add reference to assembly ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib

Comment: That's a completely different question from the one you asked... please edit your original question with as much information as possible, including the precise problem and steps you did before it happened.

Comment: Not sure it is a different question.

Comment: I copied the code from the link you suggested above. I then ran it and got the error above.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry, I hadn't realised you'd compiled it. It's after a reference to a particular library available here: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Comment: Thank you. I see a lot of this to "downlaod" they just never tell you where you are supposed to put it - could you give me a clue please?

Comment: No problem. The reason is you can place it anywhere. Your project directory is often ideal. I actually keep my gzip lib on the root of C (not recommended). In Visual Studio you can right-click your project and go to 'Add Reference'. Look under 'Browse' and select the file from there. The error should go away. HTH. Lemme know if it doesn't.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you elaborate or provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can drop in gzip.py from Python and use [IronPython.Zlib](http://bitbucket.org/jdhardy/ironpythonzlib). Some [instructions are available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734593/ironpython-how-do-i-import-gzip/3763525#3763525) on your other question.

Comment: Yes. Appreciate it - I have responded there